# How to disable jquery mobile ajax on refresh

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I'm trying to use jquery mobile with local file links but it's not working correctly for me.
I can load the initial page fine when opening the page from finder. in the address bar i see the full file path

```
    file://localhost/Users/me/[pathToMyApp]/www/index.html#/page1
```

However, when I press refresh in chrome, or simply copy page url into another window, I get the error

```
    Error loading Ajax Page
```

Is there a basic step I'm missing?

Here is my page:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script language="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
                         $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                         $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
                         });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-id="myFooter" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false">link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false">link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax="false">link3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some investigation, The issue is because JQuery and AngularJS was not working well together.

AngularJS uses hash tags to delimit routes for its controller.

jQueryMobile tries to be smart about handling hashes, which totally messes up the urls.

it's working now after I patched jquery mobile with my private fix. (as in disable hash handling).. It's working now.

Comment: seems the issue has been found and resolved here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/angular/jquery$20mobile/angular/-BufJRGQ6-M/bYa6AfCSTVYJ

Answer (score 0):

The basic step that you're missing is serving your pages with http server.

It's intentional Chrome's behavior, which restricts ajax calls to files on filesystem.

To be able to normally and effectively develop your jQM application just install and use one of the web servers. There are plenty of them for any platform.

**It's not recommended** but you can force chrome to allow you this by starting it with flags

```
--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Comment: I enabled chrome to load files from disk by starting from cmdline  with the --allow-file-access-from-files  thus it should not be a problem with this restriction.  It works with a non jquery-mobile site just fine, thus jquery-mobile is causing this behavior..

Comment: You might need the other flag. See updated answer. But you better off use some lightweight web serve for development.

Comment: tried it, unfortunately it's still not working.  The problem with the web server is that I'm using phonegap, which would load html files via file:// in the end, so having a web server won't work.